# Argument of type '{ id: number; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I get these error. what do i do?

`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

//declaring the colors
const colorSequence = [
  { "color":  "#3db44b" },
  { "color":  "#bfef45" },
  { "color":  "#42d3f4" },
  { "color":  "#4263d8" },
  { "color":  "#f68232" },
  { "color":  "#fee118" },
  { "color":  "#e6194a" },
  { "color":  "#f032e6" },
  { "color":  "#921eb3" }
]

function App() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState([])

  //shuffle the colors
  const shuffleColors = () => {
    const shuffledColors = [...colorSequence]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((color) => ({ ...color, id: Math.random() }))

      setColors(shuffledColors)
  }

setColors(shuffledColors) returns an error of
```

Argument of type '{ id: number; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
Type '{ id: number; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
Type '{ id: number; color: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)

```
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nWXL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nWXL.png)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the type definition of the `colors` stateful variable.

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState<{ color: string, id: number }[]>([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Argument of type '{ id: number; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

You are missing the *type* when setting the state.

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState<{ color: string; id?: number }[]>([]);
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd5qAbaAZSQEcBXJGtJOAF44AbXJw4AbzgAiZtBkAuCTIDEAZgAmAIwAsu7TLgBfADTips%20VCUrV2zEky6ArEbMXpciCxvLZqroATJrqzu7mEl7WtgHBAGxaABwRnlY%20Cv5qmPFJQepBqVHpvrHZSEgAjJUpJpGW3qVZqkjxlQCcuihFDTHNmAAMBa090Rl%20du1BlUja6u7kALqUmFx8MMC0cACCYGAAFACUUhbU9PAi1nSmcHRIMADC43SLQojEMAB0XHesMCgwJAAHmk1mUDCgwBoAHMTCJFgA%20fbww4UCwAenRdAAFlxMJgmAIYNiBFdTrQGLdcfjCU9fHQ3kchAiThIJGdKTi8QSkJo6dAGcIRJ8RdZ2NxePxlmy2Z86NAYPsmYIWQBZAHYz5QFA0TS4JkAWjgA0%20LkOFhlnxAKAO%202sxxVcH20hFn2sN2AmmU6uJWp1epATOMh3NFrZd0ez32XJpvP5UDoqIsxkoEiIMC4UBocBoXCYTAoEmMQA)

Comment: I think his `colors` variable is an array of objects which have an `id` property, not just a `color` property.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the type definition of the **colors** state variable.To solved this error there is two way.

**1st way**

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState<{ color: string, id: number }[]>([]);
```

**2nd way**

Follow Below 2 steps:

1. make one **interface** of colors like below.

   interface colors
   {

   color: String,

   id: Number

   }

2. Assign interface to the state.

   **const [colors, setColors] = useState< colors >([])**